# Problems appending to a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a pretty simple piece of code where I'm trying to create a dictionary, wherein, the value for every key is a list. If the key exists, then I'd like to append to the list. If the value doesn't exist, then I'd like to create a list.

I'm using the following piece of code to do this:

```
artifact_content_data = {}
for i in range(0,len(content_data)):
    for key in json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data']).keys():
        if key in artifact_content_data:
            print('Key exists')
            print(json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key])
            print(type(json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key]))
            print(artifact_content_data[key])
            artifact_content_data[key] = artifact_content_data[key].append(json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key])
            print(artifact_content_data)
            print('\n')
        else:
            print('Key does not exist')
            print(key)
            print(json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key])
            artifact_content_data[key] = [json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key]]
            print(artifact_content_data)
            print('\n')
```

For some reason, when the key doesn't exist, I'm able to create a list. But when the key already exists, somehow I'm unable to append to the list. Here's the output I'm getting:

```
    Key does not exist
type1
0
{'type1': [0]}


Key does not exist
type2
0
{'type1': [0], 'type2': [0]}


Key does not exist
type3
0
{'type1': [0], 'type2': [0], 'type3': [0]}


Key does not exist
type4
0
{'type1': [0], 'type2': [0], 'type3': [0], 'type4': [0]}


Key does not exist
type5
0
{'type1': [0], 'type2': [0], 'type3': [0], 'type4': [0], 'type5': [0]}


Key exists
0
<class 'int'>
[0]
{'type1': None, 'type2': [0], 'type3': [0], 'type4': [0], 'type5': [0]}


Key exists
1
<class 'int'>
[0]
{'type1': None, 'type2': None, 'type3': [0], 'type4': [0], 'type5': [0]}


Key exists
2
<class 'int'>
[0]
{'type1': None, 'type2': None, 'type3': None, 'type4': [0], 'type5': [0]}


Key exists
1
<class 'int'>
[0]
{'type1': None, 'type2': None, 'type3': None, 'type4': None, 'type5': [0]}


Key exists
0
<class 'int'>
[0]
{'type1': None, 'type2': None, 'type3': None, 'type4': None, 'type5': None}


Key exists
0
<class 'int'>
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-b1cf77736794> in <module>()
      7             print(type(json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key]))
      8             print(artifact_content_data[key])
----> 9             artifact_content_data[key] = artifact_content_data[key].append(json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key])
     10             print(artifact_content_data)
     11             print('\n')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

We can see clearly that when the loop gets into the 'Key exists' block, it doesn't append to the list. It instead makes the value `None`. I'm not sure why this would happen.

I'm printing all the relevant values in my loop to help figure out the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append` returns nothing. So the following line:

```
artifact_content_data[key] = artifact_content_data[key].append(json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key])
```

Effectively adds to the list, then overwrite the list in the dictionary with `None`. Just append to the existing list, no need to assign to the key:

```
artifact_content_data[key].append(json.loads(dict(content_data.loc[i])['content_data'])[key])
```

Comment: Ahh, that was really silly of me. Thanks so much for your answer :).

Answer (score 1):

To make this simple, use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

This literally does exactly what you asked, "If the key exists, then I'd like to append to the list. If the value doesn't exist, then I'd like to create a list."

Hope this helps :-)